# Tailwind css colors not working with next js components in turobrepo

Tags: next.js, error-handling, package, tailwind-css, turborepo

i have a project bootstraped with turborepo with tailwindcss.

```
<button
       type="submit"
       className="mt-6 border bg-blue-150 border-red-500 rounded-[8px] py-[8px] px-[12px] font-medium          text-white-25 w-full"
>
      Next
 </button>
```

When using type="submit" the background color is not working, but when remove the type="submit" the bg color is working fine. but outside of the turborepo setup this is working correctly. pls help?